# Change admin bar to default:off

Tags: theme-development, functions, customization, admin, filters

While I quite like the admin bar I actually want it to be OFF by default instead of ON ( I don't want to disable it altogether because I want users to be able to turn it on if they want - but but I don't want to have to manually turn it off for every user ) Is there a way to implement this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
add_action("user_register", "set_user_admin_bar_false_by_default", 10, 1);
function set_user_admin_bar_false_by_default($user_id) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'show_admin_bar_front', 'false' );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'show_admin_bar_admin', 'false' );
}
```

Place in theme functions file or you can make into a plugin.

Once user registers it will go and set the users admin bar prefs to false. The user can then, once logged in, set this to true.

Comment: why don't use `update_user_meta()` function? Like so: `update_user_meta( $user_id, 'show_admin_bar_front', 'false' );`

Comment: double that. +1 for @Brady Should work seamless, even when nicer with Mamadukas addition. Btw: This one should become a WPSE plugin ;)

Comment: Yup you are absolutely right. I was in a hurry to post and didn't research alternate methods. Ill update answer to use this instead.

Comment: sounds like it will work and be an interesting bit of code - thanks - i cant try it out till monday though.... edit ... blimey never heard of WPSE plugins before , what a resource will have to have a good look

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-bar-default-off/ can now get this as a plugin. Nice to see someone has already down voted my plugin, beyond me why...

Comment: @Brady no accounting for people is there - thanks for your help - will try this now

Comment: works perfect ( i just put the code in functions.php ) am going to use it in every project - in my opinion this is how wordpress should have done it - admin bar is great but is an "extra" as i see it not a default

Comment: If I read the docs correctly, the 'show_admin_bar_admin' key is deprecated now. Setting only 'show_admin_bar_front' should suffice. See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18811

Answer (score 2):

```
function wpse29210_admin_bar_toogle()
{
    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );

    $user = get_userdata( $GLOBALS['current_user'] )->data->ID;

    if ( ! is_admin() && $user->show_admin_bar_front )
        add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_true' );

    if ( is_admin() && $user->show_admin_bar_admin )
        add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_true' );

    return;
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse29210_admin_bar_toogle' );
```

Comment: I thought that was the code to get rid of it altogether ?

Comment: Please see update ...

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm not sure what that code is meant to do. What I want is for wordpress to have "Show Admin Bar when viewing site" unchecked by default when a new user is setup.

Comment: It's meant to disable the admin bar per default. If a user saves his profile with one of the two fields checked, then the admin bar is shown. I'm sorry, but I guess you won't be able to uncheck per default unless you add some js to the `admin_head` to disable it.

Comment: Maybe you can hook into the account creation process and set `show_admin_bar_front` and `show_admin_bar_admin` to false? Just an idea

Comment: no worries - I thought it might be a simple hook - thanks for help. I really think wordpress should have this off by default .... just my 2c.

Comment: byronyasgur: Where's your problem? What @Brady suggested sounds like a good Idea.

Comment: sorry - i think it must have sounded too much like a long shot at the time - i should have researched it really, but i was just looking for a quick fix if one existed.

Answer (score -1):

This finally works:

```
wp_update_user( array ( 'ID' => $user_id, 'show_admin_bar_front' => 'false' ) ) ;
```

Comment: How/What does this add to the existing solutions?